# Ormlite ObjectCache returning old data

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm using Ormlite on Android and with the ObjectCache enabled, I get old data back after updating the table with an UpdateBuilder and a ColumnExpression.  I have read through the doc and it does not warn against using the UpdateBuilder with the cache enabled.

The settings table should have just 1-5ish rows max.  The updateColumnExpression seems like an easy way to allow only one of the rows to be true.

Is this the expected behavior?

```
public void setActiveSetting(String id)
{
    try {
        UpdateBuilder<Settings, Integer> updateBuilder2 = getHelper().getSettingsDao().updateBuilder();
        updateBuilder2.updateColumnExpression("active", "id = " + id );
        updateBuilder2.update();
    } catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is the call that returns the outdated data:

```
public List<Settings> getSettings() 
{
    List<Settings> settings = null;
    try  {
        settings = getHelper().getSettingsDao().queryForAll();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return settings;
}
```

And the settings DAO:

```
public Dao<Settings, Integer> getSettingsDao() 
{
    if (null == settingsDao) {
        try {
            settingsDao = getDao(Settings.class);
            settingsDao.setObjectCache(true);
        } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return settingsDao;
}
```

Disabling the ObjectCache does return the correct data, but this data is fetched quite frequently, so I'd like to keep it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this the expected behavior?

Unfortunately, yes.  If you had updated the object using `dao.update(...);` then the cache would know that the object needed to be refreshed.  By using the `UpdateBuilder` to make mass changes to the table, there is no way for the cache to know which objects were affected.

You will need to clear the cache after your call to the `UpdateBuilder` finishes.

Comment: Clearing the cache works, thanks for the quick reply.  Great work on the ORM, I like it a lot.